# What is the secret behind www.rataalada.com from The Batman movie 2022?

Tags: the-batman-2022

We can visit the site [www.rataalada.com](https://www.rataalada.com) from The Batman post-credit scene and it has some message from Riddler I believe. I was able to download a ZIP file from the page. Does anybody know what's this all about?

Comment: Asked and answered on Puzzling.SE: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/115182/31839

Comment: @F1Krazy - that content has now been replaced - it apparently changes frequently.

Answer (score 6):

It's a teaser for the next movie.
The site's content apparently changes rapidly - today's was

[image]

The download is a series of images, some with text that needs deciphering.

[image]

[The Batman's Post-Credits Scene Is More of a Post-Credits Riddle](https://www.menshealth.com/entertainment/a39353216/the-batman-is-there-a-post-credits-scene/) covers some of the earlier content, and there is a QA on Puzzling.SE about some of this content [now gone from the rataalada site] - ["The Batman" puzzle: rataalada.com](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115182/the-batman-puzzle-rataalada-com).